# Switch role after connecting to database

Tags: postgresql

Is it possible to change the postgresql role a user is using when interacting with postgres after the initial connection?

The database(s) will be used in a web application and I'd like to employ database level rules on tables and schemas with connection pooling. From reading the postgresql documentation it appears I can switch roles if I originally connect as a user with the superuser role, but I would prefer to initially connect as a user with minimal permissions and switch as necessary. Having to specify the user's password when switching would be fine (in fact I'd prefer it).

What am I missing?

**Update**: I've tried both `SET ROLE` and `SET SESSION AUTHORIZATION` as suggested by @Milen however neither command seems to work if the user is not a superuser:

```
$ psql -U test
psql (8.4.4)
Type "help" for help.

test=> \du test
          List of roles
 Role name | Attributes |   Member of    
-----------+------------+----------------
 test      |            | {connect_only}

test=> \du test2
          List of roles
 Role name | Attributes |   Member of    
-----------+------------+----------------
 test2     |            | {connect_only}

test=> set role test2;
ERROR:  permission denied to set role "test2"
test=> \q
```

Answer (score 70):

```
--create a user that you want to use the database as:

create role neil;

--create the user for the web server to connect as:

create role webgui noinherit login password 's3cr3t';

--let webgui set role to neil:

grant neil to webgui; --this looks backwards but is correct.
```

`webgui` is now in the `neil` group, so `webgui` can call `set role neil` . However, `webgui` did not inherit `neil`'s permissions.

Later, login as webgui:

```
psql -d some_database -U webgui
(enter s3cr3t as password)

set role neil;
```

`webgui` does not need `superuser` permission for this.

You want to `set role` at the beginning of a database session and reset it at the end of the session. In a web app, this corresponds to getting a connection from your database connection pool and releasing it, respectively. Here's an example using Tomcat's connection pool and Spring Security:

```
public class SetRoleJdbcInterceptor extends JdbcInterceptor {

    @Override
    public void reset(ConnectionPool connectionPool, PooledConnection pooledConnection) {

        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

        if(authentication != null) {
            try {

                /* 
                  use OWASP's ESAPI to encode the username to avoid SQL Injection. Can't use parameters with SET ROLE. Need to write PG codec.

                  Or use a whitelist-map approach
                */
                String username = ESAPI.encoder().encodeForSQL(MY_CODEC, authentication.getName());

                Statement statement = pooledConnection.getConnection().createStatement();
                statement.execute("set role \"" + username + "\"");
                statement.close();
            } catch(SQLException exp){
                throw new RuntimeException(exp);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {

        if("close".equals(method.getName())){
            Statement statement = ((Connection)proxy).createStatement();
            statement.execute("reset role");
            statement.close();
        }

        return super.invoke(proxy, method, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: What I found really useful about this answer was that "GRANT neil TO webgui;" meant that webgui becomes a 'member' of neil...and is able to do thing like 'ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES', which I was previously unable todo.

Answer (score 22):

Take a look at ["SET ROLE"](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-set-role.html) and ["SET SESSION AUTHORIZATION"](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-set-session-authorization.html).

Comment: I've tried both commands to no avail, if the connecting user isn't a superuser I get permission denied errors. I've updated the question with additional information

Comment: I believe your user has to be a member of the ROLES you already want to set and have the NOINHERITS property on their user so that they're not default on.  Then you should be escalate and de-escalate.  But they have to be a member of the ROLE already.

Answer (score 4):

If someone still needs it (like I do).

> The specified role_name must be a role that the current session user is a member of.
>   https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/sql-set-role.html

We need to make the current session user a member of the role:

```
create role myrole;
set role myrole;
grant myrole to myuser;
set role myrole;
```

produces:

```
Role ROLE created.


Error starting at line : 4 in command -
set role myrole
Error report -
ERROR: permission denied to set role "myrole"

Grant succeeded.


Role SET succeeded.
```