# How does the postgresql (set role user) command use in SSM projects?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, mybatis, connection-pool

Now the project is using springmvc+ spring + mybatis + druid + postgresql
The users in the project correspond to the users in the database, so each time you run SQL, you switch the users with the (set role user) command and then perform the crud operations of the database.

My question:
Because there are many connections in the connection pool, the first step is to get the connection of the database, then switch users, and then perform the operation of business SQL on the database. But I don't know which part of the project this logic should be processed, because the connection of the connection pool and the execution of SQL are implemented by the underlying code. Do you have any good plans?
Can you provide me with a complete demo, such as the following operations:

Step 1, get the user's name from spring security (or shiro).

Step 2, Get the connection currently using the database from the connection pool.

Step 3, execute SQL (set role user) to switch roles.

Step 4, perform crud operation.

Step 5, Reset the database connection(reset role)

Comment: `Can you provide me with a complete demo.` Shirley you can't be serious? However, you might want to look at [schema based multitenancy](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-5-multitenancy) which is related. In that it's the schema that's changed for every call, not the role.

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice,Because some changes have been made in postgresql; the database is encrypted according to the permissions of the roles, and the permissions are designed in the database (for example, a table has three fields, Mike users can only see two fields on login, while Tom users can see one field on login). The web project only needs to tell the role of database login. Get the corresponding data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple way to do what you need with the help of [mybatis-spring](http://www.mybatis.org/spring/).

Unless you already use mybatis-spring the first step would be to change the configuration of your project so that you obtain `SqlSessionFactory` using `org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean` provided by mybatis-spring.

The next step is the implementation of setting/resetting the user role for the connection. In mybatis the connection lifecycle is controlled by the class implementing `org.apache.ibatis.transaction.Transaction` interface. The instance of this class is used by the query executor to get the connection.

In a nutshell you need to create your own implementation of this class and configure mybatis to use it.

Your implementation can be based on the `SpringManagedTransaction` from mybatis-spring and would look something like:

```
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;

class UserRoleAwareSpringManagedTransaction extends SpringManagedTransaction {

  public UserRoleAwareSpringManagedTransaction(DataSource dataSource) {
    super(dataSource);
  }

  @Override
  public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
    Connection connection = getCurrentConnection();
    setUserRole(connection);
    return connection;
  }

  private Connection getCurrentConnection() {
    return super.getConnection();
  }

  @Override
  public void close() throws SQLException {
    resetUserRole(getCurrentConnection());
    super.close();
  }  

  private void setUserRole(Connection connection) {
    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    String username = authentication.getName();
    Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
    try {
      // note that this direct usage of usernmae is a subject for SQL injection
      // so you need to use the suggestion from
      // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998597/switch-role-after-connecting-to-database
      // about encoding of the username
      statement.execute("set role '" + username + "'");
    } finally {
      statement.close();
    }
  }

  private void resetUserRole(Connection connection) {
    Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
    try {
      statement.execute("reset role");
    } finally {
      statement.close();
    }
  }

}
```

Now you need to configure mybatis to use you `Transaction` implementation. For this you need to implement `TransactionFactory` similar to `org.mybatis.spring.transaction.SpringManagedTransactionFactory` provided by [mybatis-spring](http://www.mybatis.org/spring/):

```
public class UserRoleAwareSpringManagedTransactionFactory implements TransactionFactory {
  @Override
  public Transaction newTransaction(DataSource dataSource, TransactionIsolationLevel level, boolean autoCommit) {
    return new UserRoleAwareSpringManagedTransaction(dataSource);
  }
  @Override
  public Transaction newTransaction(Connection conn) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("New Spring transactions require a DataSource");
  }
  @Override
  public void setProperties(Properties props) {
  }
}
```

And then define a bean of type `UserRoleAwareSpringManagedTransactionFactory` in your spring context and inject it into `transactionFactory` property of the `SqlSessionFactoryBeen` in your spring context.

Now every time mybatis obtains a `Connection` the implementation of `Transaction` will set the current spring security user to set the role.

Comment: Thank you so much. Your answer helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Best practice is that database users are applications. Application users' access to particular data/resource should be controlled in the application. Applications should not rely on database to restrict data/resource access. Therefore, application users should not have different roles in database. An application should use only a single database user account.

Spring is manifestation of best practices. Therefore, Spring does not implement this functionality. If you want such functionality, you need to hack.

Referring to [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/78353/set-role-via-parameterized-query), your best bet is to:

```
@Autowired JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate; 

// ...

public runPerUserSql() {

    jdbcTemplate.execute("set role user 'user_1';");
    jdbcTemplate.execute("SELECT 1;");

}
```

I still do not have much confidence in this. Unless you are writing a pgAdmin webapp for multiple users, you should re-consider your approach and design.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't provide a full demo as this will require a lot of hacking. I strongly suggest you revise your design as it is not very common.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Some changes have been made in the database. This design is not a problem. Now the most important thing is that when combining with the project, there are some problems.