# Is it legitimate to use the Postgres role system for web app authentication and role management?

Tags: postgresql, authentication, web-applications, roles

## MY SITUATION

I want to create my first end-to-end web application using **React** and **Postgres**. I did use Postgres in a previous job within an intranet and used the Postgres role system for user authentication.

## THE ROLES

My planned web app would be a **team planning system**. It would consist of the following user roles:

- **web admin** (me, the superuser)
- **team admin** (can INSERT / DROP users within his/her team, set globally
  applied feature settings for the team, etc.)
- **team user** (can adjust custom personal settings stored in the
  database, e.g. colors, own profile)
- **visitor** (can only view a team and its members)

## MY APPROACH

My current plan for authentication & role management of users would be to have the above-mentioned roles as Postgres group roles and within each group role, the login role for the corresponding user is located. So the user authentication would be purely managed by Postgres' inbuild role system.

Different data accesses are then applied through

- table-based and column-based privilege [GRANT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/sql-grant.html)s plus the implementation of views for each group role and
- [row security policies](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-rowsecurity.html) for subsetting data to the corresponding team
  of a user.

Is this a good approach?

Comment: From a database perspective there is nothing wrong with such an approach.

Comment: After some more research I don't know if I (1) should use the actual login role system of postgres or (2) only use group roles and have a table of users in a different schema. Also, I see that connection pooling might become an issue with my approach (as mentioned by @JGH )

Comment: Connection pooling is a real concern. But if you use login roles per group, it might still be feasible.

Comment: Actually I found this (rather old) [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998597/switch-role-after-connecting-to-database) that might be helpful for me. It seems with this I could successfully establish connection pooling

Answer (score 1):

While feasible, it may not be the simplest approach.

Issues will arise when you will start to use connection pooling. Each time you will make a request to the DB, you will have to switch user first.

Also, one day the wrong user will be used (forget to switch or else) but it will be nearly impossible to debug or even to find out: you would have logged that `Bob` updated table X, not that `R_Readonly_worker` updated it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What I am confused about is your statement "_Each time you will make a request to the DB, you will have to switch user first_". Do you mean if another users uses the same connection of a previous user my output for `current_user` would be different?

Comment: @JoeBe Yes, because in a connection pool, the connections are not closed but simply "returned to the pool", so session parameters (such as the current user!) remain

Comment: What about using the suggestions explained in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998597/switch-role-after-connecting-to-database)?

Comment: @JoeBe that's exactly what I am saying: you would have to do this before every command, else you will be using another user (the last one that did a `set role` in this pooled connection)