# How to dynamically change db role according to logged-in user

Tags: postgresql, glassfish, java-ee-7, payara

I set in my application server (Payara 5.193) a jdbc realm and a jdbc connection pool.
Everything works fine, but I want to change the current_user of my connection with the name of the user logged in my application. For this purpose I created in my database 1 role for each user of my application.
The idea is to change the role when the logged user works with the application, so I can see who is working and track the modification (I implemented shadow tables).

I tried to execute SET ROLE after login and RESET ROLE after logout, but without success. I think that to make it works is necessary execute SET ROLE every time the application run queries to the db, but I can't understand how I can do this.

How can I get the desired behavior?

Thanks

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998597/switch-role-after-connecting-to-database?rq=1

Comment: I had already read. The JdbcInceptor class is from Tomcat library but I'm working with Payara.