# How to connect to PostgreSQL with different users and different privileges

Tags: postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy, database-connection, connection-pooling

I have created a **Flask** application using **SQLAlchemy** as the ORM. I also use **flask-login** to manage my different users. I want to connect to a **PostgreSQL** database with different flask users that correspond to different postgres users that have different privileges.
They should be able to be logged in at the same time and make different queries with their individual rights. I tried all kinds of pooling methods by SQLAlchemy, but could not manage to achieve what I want. It always led to an arbitrary association of the open connections to the different users.  What is the best way to do this, i.e. to achieve this kind of "session-persistent" database connection behaviour?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: I _believe_ you would need to execute `SET ROLE` at the beginning of each _session_, as described for pure postgres in this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2998597/5320906).  So it would have to be done dynamically for each request.